# 00933. 00000 - "SQL command not properly ended" DYNAMIC SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR c_ddy (p_table_name VARCHAR2, p_table_name_2 VARCHAR2)
   IS
      (SELECT column_name
         FROM (  SELECT column_name
                   FROM user_tab_columns
                  WHERE table_name = p_table_name
               ORDER BY column_name));

   TYPE t_content IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2 (9000)
      INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   a_content   t_content;
   l_sql       VARCHAR2 (1000);
BEGIN
   FOR r_ddy IN c_ddy ('TABLE_a', 'TABLE_B')
   LOOP
      l_sql :=
            'SELECT  '
         || r_ddy.column_name
         || ' FROM TABLE_A '
         || 'MINUS'
         || 'SELECT  '
         || r_ddy.column_name
         || 'FROM TABLE_B';

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql BULK COLLECT INTO a_content;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_sql);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Trying to output every column in TABLE_A minus every column in TABLE_B.

Comment: At first glance it looks like there will be no space between MINUS and SELECT.  Also possibly no space before the second FROM... what is your PUT_LINE statement outputting?

Comment: im trying to loop this dynmic sql statment SELECT  * FROM TABLE a MINUS SELECT * FROM TABLE b;

Comment: If you move your `dbms_output` line *before* the `execute immediate` you'll be able to see what it tries to execute; at the moment you don't reach it. And that should make what dazedandconfused said clear, you're missing spaces - the output won't match what said you're trying to run.

Comment: im trying to loop this dynmic sql statment SELECT  * FROM TABLE a MINUS SELECT * FROM TABLE b; my put_line im trying to get all the columns in the table a and all the columns in table b using the data dictionary but  i dont know how to writ the dynamic sql statment for that.

Comment: You aren't doing `select *`, you're comparing one column at a time, via the cursor loop. Or you would be if you added the whitespace. You're also overwriting the `a_content` collection each time around the loop - it doesn't append. If you did want to do `select *` then the tables would have to have the same structure, and you wouldn't need to use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanx alot man it was Spaces Problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A space is missing in the SQL string.
Try this:

```
  l_sql :=
        'SELECT '
     || r_ddy.column_name
     || ' FROM TABLE_A '
     || ' MINUS '
     || ' SELECT '
     || r_ddy.column_name
     || ' FROM TABLE_B';
```

UPD: For some reason the spaces were gone before. Now I put them again.